# fetching contact information browser console error in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have experience site page in which i have included the LWC component. LWC component displays the contact information related to the logged in user. I have given the access to the appropriate profiles.

Here is an error which i am getting into the browser console.
[image]

Here is the glimpse of my code
**LWC JS**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc'; 
    import fetchContactInfo from 
'@salesforce/apex/NQHProfileController.fetchContactInfo'; 
import updateContactInfo from '@salesforce/apex/NQHProfileController.updateContactInfo';
        
        fetchMemberDetails() {
            fetchContactInfo()
              .then(result => {
                const dataResult = JSON.stringify(result);
                console.log("RESULT-->" + JSON.stringify(result));
                if (result) {
                                console.log('in result====>',result);
                  this.memberDetails = {
                    contactId: dataResult.ContactId, 
                    name: dataResult.FirstName + ' ' + dataResult.LastName,
                    email: dataResult.Email,
                    phone: dataResult.Phone,
                    address: {
                      street: dataResult.MailingAddress.street,
                      city: dataResult.MailingAddress.city,
                      state: dataResult.MailingAddress.state,
                      postal: dataResult.MailingAddress.postalCode
                    }
                  };
                                console.log('memberdetails====>',this.memberDetails);
                } else {
                  console.error('No contact information found');
                }
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching contact information', error);
              });   }
```

Comment: What's does the error say?

Comment: error doesn't say anything specific to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const dataResult = JSON.stringify(result);
```

You're converting the data into a string, then trying to use that string to access properties that definitely don't exist on a string (e.g. `dataResult.MailingAddress.street`). Do not convert the result to JSON.

If you're having a problem reading the data in the console (e.g. `console.log('in result====>',result);` shows `Proxy`), just know that the `Proxy` is transparent to the running code. It's used to implement a read-only property on the data result.